# How do I free up space previously assigned to BLOBs?

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob

I've been asked to free up the space assigned to BLOBS in Oracle. I will be extracting the data and then setting the BLOB to null to free up space.

According to the DBA this does not free up the space. SQL I am using is

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET BLOB_FIELD_A = NULL
```

I did some googling and there is a function called `EMPTY_BLOB()`; No comment anywhere that it frees up the previously allocated space

Comment: There is no need to shout.

Comment: That does free up the space - just not on the filesystem, only inside the tablespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way to shrink a segment in oracle is to MOVE/SHRINK it.

ie you have to run, once you've updated the lobs to null:

```
alter table b modify lob (c) (shrink space);
```

(available from 10.2 onwards)
or

```
alter table b move lob(c) store as (tablespace your_tablespace);
```

Comment: Thanks. My DBA will be happy